# Perl: using variable in substitution

Tags: regex, perl, eval, substitution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a variable in the replacement side of the Perl substitution operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator)

I would like to do something like

```
$sub = "\\1";
$match = "hi(.*)";
$str = "hi1234"
$res = $str;
$res =~ s/$match/$sub/g
```

I would like this to return `1234` but in this case it returns `\1`. I.e. I want it to be equivalent to `s/$match/\1/g` does anyone know how to do this?