# How to save a substitution regex (search/replace) in a variable, similar to qr//

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to store a `s/ / /g` regex as a variable (without much luck).

Here is an example that uses a normal match to show what I intend to do.

```
my %file_structure = (
    header => qr/just another/,
    table  => qr/perl beginner/,
)
```

Now I can call this using `$line =~ $file_structure{'header'}` and it will return `undef`, or `true` if the pattern matches.

However I would like to say `$line =~ $file_structure{'foo'}` where `$file_structure{'foo'}` contains something like `s/beginner/hacker/g`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should store the 2 parts separately:

```
my %file_structure = (
    foo => {pat => qr/beginner/, repl => 'hacker'},
);

my $line = 'just another perl beginner';
$line =~ s/$file_structure{foo}{pat}/$file_structure{foo}{repl}/;
print "$line\n";
```

Which would be much safer than resorting to an evil "eval EXPR":

```
my %file_structure = (
    foo => 's/beginner/hacker/',
);

my $line = 'just another perl beginner';
eval "\$line =~ $file_structure{foo}";
print "$line\n";
```

Comment: The exception is if you need to represent flags like `/e` or `/g` somewhere, because those cannot be represented in the LHS like `/x` or `/i` can.  You have to either use the same substitutions flags every time, or use a run-time string  `eval` when you cannot.

Comment: You have to use this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator if you want to include a captured expression in the right hand side. It's safer, anyways, and more general

Answer (score 9):

As you have found, there is no way to directly store a substitution regex like you can a match regex (with `qr//`).  You can break the parts up and recombine them as tadmc shows.  Another way to do this is to store the substitution in a subroutine:

```
my %file_structure = (
   foo_uses_default => sub {s/foo/bar/},
   foo_takes_arg    => sub {$_[0] =~ s/foo/bar/},
   foo_does_either  => sub {(@_ ? $_[0] : $_) =~ s/foo/bar/},
);

$file_structure{foo_uses_default}() for ...;
$file_structure{foo_uses_arg}($_)   for ...;
```

Comment: You could also do `map $file_structure{foo_whatever}, ...` and I believe any of those three versions would be suitable for an expression to pass in that case.