# How to search and replace (substitute) by using keys and values of a hash

Tags: perl, hash, replace, substitution

I think my problem is pretty similar to this one:
[How to use a variable in the replacement side of the Perl substitution operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator)
The difference is, $find and $replace are the keys and values of a hash i am using.

```
while(($find,$replace) = each %hash){
$string_to_check =~ s/$find/$replace/e;
}
```

Here's an example for one pair of key-value-pair in my hash

key: ^/abc(/.*)?$

value: www.abc.website.com$1

I get an substitution here, but the $1 won't be replaced by the content of (/.*)

With s///ee instead of s///e, i get:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "//xyz"
(Missing operator before xyz?)
Use of uninitialized value in substitution iterator at ./script line 46, <FH1> line 3470.
```

...and therefore the matching parts are replaced with an empty string.

I am assuming, that

```
while(($find,$replace) = each %hash)
```

won't do the same as the single quotes in the first answer to the other question in the  thread i linked to:

```
$replace='"foo $foo bar"';
```

Is that right?

Excuse my English and Thanks for your help in advance.
(I am new to Perl and Programming in general.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate the $1 stored in $replace you will need to use `eval`. Note that `eval` can be a security risk, so make sure you control the contents of `%hash`.

```
while (my ($find, $replace) = each %hash) {
    eval "\$string_to_check =~ s{$find}{$replace}";
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for response. Now i need to find out why this does the job - i didn't know about 'eval'.

Comment: Thanks again! I saw eval in the other thread (with the similar problem) but i thought it was the same as s///e. But it makes a difference. Thank you! After 2 days of searching, i got it ;)

Comment: I've [recently learned](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=930010) that there may well be a safer way than the `eval`. [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/~nobull/String-Interpolate-0.3/lib/String/Interpolate.pm)::[RE](http://search.cpan.org/~djerius/String-Interpolate-RE-0.03/lib/String/Interpolate/RE.pm) which I haven't used yet, but sounds nifty.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `$1` in your replacement use `\1`. It's the backreference to the first matched group.  I think in that case you can also drop `/e` entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I changed it to \1 but it won't replace it with the content of (/.*) either - so i get abc.website.com\1 now