# Substitution to change file path

Tags: perl, substitution

I'm trying to change the directory path as shown in the code, but it just wont work.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm expecting `$fulltitle` to be `\\mynas\data\music\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3`

```
my $find = 'C:\Users\Bell';
my $replace = '\\mynas\data\music';
my $fulltitle = 'C:\Users\Bell\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3';
$fulltitle =~ s/$find/$replace/;
print ("$fulltitle\n");
```

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator

Answer (score 5):

[quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $find      = quotemeta 'C:\Users\Bell';
my $replace   = '\\mynas\data\music';
my $fulltitle = 'C:\Users\Bell\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3';
$fulltitle =~ s/$find/$replace/;
print("$fulltitle\n");

__END__

\mynas\data\music\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3
```

[warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) would have given you a clue as to what was wrong.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'd never heard of quotemeta before so thanks for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $find      = 'C:\Users\Bell';
my $replace   = '\\mynas\data\music';
my $fulltitle = 'C:\Users\Bell\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3';

$fulltitle    =~ s/\Q$find\E/${replace}/;
print "$fulltitle\n";
```

---

You need to use `\Q` and `\E` to disable the backslash metacharacter in the match.
[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/tO4yud5m)

---

***Note:** the replacement will translate the `\\` to `\`*

Comment: No idea what \Q and \E do exactly ... but only solution that worked when "\" are part of the search and replace. Even if within single brackets. (Only taken an hour to find this solutiion!)

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating paths with regex sucks.

```
use Path::Class::Dir qw();
use Path::Class::File qw();
my $old = Path::Class::Dir->new_foreign('Win32', 'C:\Users\Bell');
my $new = Path::Class::Dir->new_foreign('Win32', '\\\\mynas\data\music');
my $file = Path::Class::File->new_foreign('Win32', 'C:\Users\Bell\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3');
$file->relative($old)->absolute($new)->stringify
# '\\mynas\data\music\FABRICLive\17 - Rhodes For D - Furney.mp3'
```

You made a mistake in the notation of the directory with the [UNC path](http://enwp.org/UNC_path). Double backslashes in string literals must be escaped with backslashes, that's just how [the syntax](http://p3rl.org/op#q%2fSTRING%2f) works.