# Perl using $1 in a substitution replacement with variable interpolation

Tags: perl, variables, interpolation

I am trying to use variable interpolation in a replacement string including `$1`, `$2`,...
However, I can't get it to expand `$1` into the replacement.  I eventually will have the
`$pattern` and `$replacement` variables be read from a configuration file, but even
setting them manually doesn't work.

In the example script, you can see that the `$1` (which should be 'DEF') is not
expanded in `$new_name`, but it is in `$new_name2` (without variables).

Adding an 'e' flag to the substitution doesn't help.

How do I fix this?

Matt

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;

my $old_name = 'ABC_DEF_GHI';

my $pattern = 'ABC_(...)_GHI';
my $replacement = 'CBA_${1}_IHG';

# using variables - doesn't work
my $new_name = $old_name;
$new_name =~ s|$pattern|$replacement|;

printf("%s --> %s\n", $old_name, $new_name);


# not using variables - does work
my $new_name2 = $old_name;
$new_name2 =~ s|ABC_(...)_GHI|CBA_${1}_IHG|;

printf("%s --> %s\n", $old_name, $new_name2);
```

OUTPUT:

```
ABC_DEF_GHI --> CBA_${1}_IHG
ABC_DEF_GHI --> CBA_DEF_IHG
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a variable in the replacement side of the Perl substitution operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator)

Comment: The sol'n I went with was: `$new_name =~ s|$pattern|qq("$replacement")|ee;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this changes in your code:

```
my $replacement = '"CBA_$1_IHG"';  #note the single and double quotes
# ...
$new_name =~ s|$pattern|$replacement|ee;  #note the double "ee", double evaluation
```

[See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator/392717#392717) for more information

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392643/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-replacement-side-of-the-perl-substitution-operator/392717#392717 for explanation

Comment: Note that this can be used to execute arbitrary Perl code, since the second `e` stands for `eval`, as in `eval EXPR`.

Answer (score 3):

`/e` treat `$replacement` as Perl code. The Perl code `$replacement` simply returns the value it contains.

If you want to evaluate the *contents* of `$replacement` as Perl code, you need

```
s/$search/ my $s = eval $replacement; die $@ if $@; $s /e
```

which can be written as

```
s/$search/$replacement/ee
```

Note that since `$replacement` is expected to contain Perl code, it means that this can be used to execute arbitrary Perl code.

A better solution is to realise you are writing your own subpar templating system, and use an existing one instead. [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aInterpolate) understands the templating syntax you are currently using:

```
use String::Interpolate qw( interpolate );
s/$search/interpolate $replace/e
```