# Perl regular expression -- dynamic replacement using eval, literal $1 being used in replacement

Tags: regex, perl, eval, substitution

I am using eval to handle a dynamic replacement regular expression.

The value capture on the left side ($1) is not being used on the right side of the regexp.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $string = "test-txt";

# Attempt 1
my $regexp_m = '-(\S+)$';
my $regexp_r = '.$1';
my $string2 = eval{ $string =~ s/$regexp_m/$regexp_r/; return $string; };

# Attempt 2
my $regexp = 's/(\S+)$/.$1/';
my $string3 = eval{ $string =~ $regexp; return $string; return $string; };

print "Attempt 1: $string2\n";
print "Attempt 2: $string3\n";

exit;
```

Output:

Attempt 1: test.$1

Attempt 2: test.$1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As daxim comments, [this answer by Ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392717/50552) contains a solution.  The [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) says you can use the `/ee` regex modifier to:

> Evaluate the right side as a string then eval the result.

Ysth passes `'".$1"'` as the right-hand side of the replacement regex.  The `/ee` modifier first evaluates this string to `".$1"`. After that, `eval` replaces `$1` with the first capture group.

Working example:

```
my $string = 'test-txt';
my $regexp_m = '-(\S+)$';
my $regexp_r = '".$1"';      # Note the double quotes, so it's a string in a string
$string =~ s/$regexp_m/$regexp_r/ee;
print "$string\n";
```