# How to replace a xml by regex checklist

Tags: regex, perl

I have a xml file and some replace check list for replace xml file. How can escape regex and replace that xml file. Just I tried that concept but It can't work perfectly... how can I do this?

I Tried:

Input xml:

```
<xml>
<p class="text">The <em type="italic">end</em> of the text</p>
<p class="text">The <bold type="strong">end of the</bold> text</p>
<p class="text">The end of <samll type="caps">the<small> text</p>
</xml>
```

script:

```
use strict;
open(IN, "xml_file.xml") || die "can't open $!";
my $text = join '', <IN>;
my @ar = '';
my $testing;
foreach my $t (<DATA>){
    @ar = split /\t/, $t;
    chomp($ar[0]);
    chomp($ar[1]);
    $text =~ s/$ar[0]/$ar[1]/segi;
}
print $text;

__END__
<p([^>]+)?> <line>
<small([^>]+)?> <sc$1>
<bold type=\"([^"]+)\"> <strong act=\"$1\">
<(\/)?em([^>]+)?>   <$1emhasis$2>
```

need output:

```
<xml>
<line>The <emhasis type="italic">end</emhasis> of the text</line>
<line>The <strong act="strong">end of the</strong> text</line>
<line>The end of <sc type="caps">the<sc> text</line>
</xml>
```

How can I replace this tag regex as checklist and how can I get value from group pattern..

Comment: what output do you actually get when you run this?

Comment: `$text =~ s/$ar[1]/$ar[1]/segi;` ??? Your RE is wrong. I think you want `$text =~ s/$ar[0]/$ar[1]/segi;`

Comment: Oh and you chomp the wrong ones, its `chomp($ar[0]);chomp($ar[1]);` not `1,2` The array starts with 0, not 1

Comment: what @Paulchenkiller said seems very likely

Comment: But really, there are so many possible problems that unless we see your output, it's tough to tell exactly what's going on

Comment: Do all your input `<p>` tags take up single lines only? Does one of these tags ever wrap to 2 input lines?

Comment: Ok, But I have give input xml and output xml file with some listout tags to replace in regex format. How can possible this replace by perl script...

Comment: @jithi, source is $ar[0], my output as $[1], so many tag list out this format. I have that format as seperate file so that list out get and replace a xml file by perl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to an [old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392717/976596), You need to use double eval substitution.

I can't make it working using `<DATA>`, but below code will work. You can make the @replace structure as you want, I just created a simple one.

```
my $text = <<XML;
<xml>
<p class="text">The <em type="italic">end</em> of the text</p>
<p class="text">The <bold type="strong">end of the</bold> text</p>
<p class="text">The end of <small type="caps">the</small> text</p>
</xml>
XML

my @replace = (
    {
        'select' => '<p([^>]+)?>',
        'replace' => '"<line$1>"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '/p>',
        'replace' => '"/line>"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '<small([^>]+)?>',
        'replace' => '"<sc$1>"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '/small>',
        'replace' => '"/sc>"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '<bold\s+type="(.+?)".*?>',
        'replace' => '"<strong act=\"$1\">"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '/bold>',
        'replace' => '"/strong>"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '<em([^>]+)?>',
        'replace' => '"<emhasis$1>"'
    },
    {
        'select' => '/em>',
        'replace' => '"/emhasis>"'
    },
);

map {my $re = $_; $text =~ s/$re->{select}/$re->{replace}/sigee;} @replace;

print $text;
```

Comment: @Mr. Jithin very nicely reply for this question.. thank you... It working very nicely...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
$ar[0] = qr/$ar[0]/;
```

just before execute the regexpr substitution;

also, you forgot this pattern:

```
</p>    </line>
```

You have a typo in the input xml:

```
<samll type="caps">
```

should be

```
<small type="caps">
```

And finally, a piece of advice: it's not a good idea parsing XML with regular expressions. I recommend using an XML parser from CPAN, is a better choice (IMO).

Comment: thanks for advice. But I have tried to how can get from regex pattern and how can get that pattern value during the replace