# How defer replacement to access var from search?

Tags: regex, perl

Basically I want to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$search = qr/(?<X>abc)/;
$_ = "123 abc 456";
s/$search/$+{X} $+{X}/;
print;
```

something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$search = qr/(?<X>abc)/;
$replace = q($+{X} $+{X});
$_ = "123 abc 456";
s/$search/$replace/;
print;
```

Result should be `123 abc abc 456`.

Is it possible?

`$replace` needs to be maintained as an external var.  So, I don't want the contents just moved to another location.  I'm reading this info from a file.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.  I need to do a double evaluate on the expression (Thanks to @Birei for pointing me at the regex evaluate command.  Still can't find it in the perl docs though... had to google. :( )

So it becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$search = qr/(?<X>abc)/;
$replace = q(qq($+{X} $+{X}));
$_ = "123 abc 456";
s/$search/$replace/ee;
print;
```

Comment: *"Still can't find it in the perl docs though."* I assume you mean `ee`? See `perldoc perlop` under `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpogce`

Comment: some flags affect actual matching and are in perlre; others are specific to s or m and are documented in perlop.  for *why* it works, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/392717/17389

Answer (score 3):

Try with a function an add a flag to evaluate the replacement part, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$search = qr/(?<X>abc)/;
$replace = sub { qq($+{X} $+{X}) };
$_ = "123 abc 456";
s/$search/$replace->()/e;
print;
```

It yields:

```
123 abc abc 456
```

Comment: Also, I can't have the contents just moved to another location.  I need to move the contents there.