# perl regex using variables

Tags: regex, perl

here is a code snippet:

```
$regex_match = "(.*).txt";
$replacement = "\$1.pdf";
my $new_replacement = ""; #???
my $new_regex_match = quotemeta ($regex_match); #???
$from = "test.txt";
(my $to = $from) =~ s{$regex_match}{$replacement}g;
print "From " . $from . " To " . $to  . "\n";
```

Output :
From test.txt To $1.pdf

I believe the $1 is not being interpolated. What needs to change? What does new_replacement and/or new_regex_match be?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `$`?

Comment: You can simplify your code by replacing extension: $from=~s/\.txt$/\.pdf/;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `s///ee` to force evaluation.

```
my $regex_match = '(.*)\.txt';
my $replacement = '$1.".pdf"';

while (<>) {
    s/$regex_match/$replacement/ee;
    print;
}
```

Comment: $replacement = '$1.".pdf"'; What does $1. do with ee option? I ask because I tested this as well $replacement = '$1".pdf"'; and received errors. Your solution did work! Thx. Just not seeing why.

Comment: @Paul ysth has an [excellent explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/392717/176646) in the question I linked this as a dupe of.

Comment: Sorry did not see the dup comment prior to my answer. It is a good explanation. @Paul The short answer is that you are evaluating Perl code, so you want this: `$1 . ".pid"`. Yours expands to `$1 ".pdf"`, which is missing the concatenation operator.

Comment: So it is a string concat on second eval? wow...